# Use boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket as a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

I´m building a communication class using `boost::asio` to encapsulate a client ftp connection. I want to create the socket on class constructor and use it during the class lifetime.

As socket needs a `io_service`, here is what I´ve done so far:

and I need to hold the open socket as a class member, as:

```
class Connect {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> currentSocket;
    bool isConnected;
}

Connect::Connect()
{
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ioService);
      socket.connect(--params--);

      if (error)
            -- handle error --

      currentSocket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(socket); <<=== ERROR HERE

      isConnected = true;
}   

Connect::~Connect()
{
    currentSocket->disconnect();
}

Connect::Read()
{
    currentSocket->async_receive(...);
}
```

The error I´m getting is:

```
c:\boost_1_60\boost\asio\basic_socket.hpp(1513): error C2248: 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>::basic_io_object' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>'
```

I´m using VS2012.

Is that the correct approach for storing the socket during the class lifetime ? 
Why is that error happening ?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is trying to make a copy of the socket, which is not allowed. The copy constructor is not public.

Why not simply create the shared pointer in the first place?

```
Connect::Connect()
{
      currentSocket = std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(ioService);
      currentSocket->connect(--params--);

      if (error)
            -- handle error --

      isConnected = true;
}
```